# React get json object in array within array & create json dropdown sorting

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I am wondering how do I get the **eventId** & **title** from the "**currentSchedule**", as you can see, "**currentSchedule**" is an array and it is inside the "**response**" array.

I was only able to loop everything out dynamically with id, title, description... etc whatever that is in the "**response**" array, but not the **currentSchedule**, that is another array. Now it is only displaying ONE same **currentSchedule** title for all lists from the JSON file. It seems abit complicated in the **currentSchedule** array, I need to get the **time** and **title** from **currentSchdule** and display it like this: [image: currentSchedule]

I am also trying to add a sorting dropdown that allows users to filter the list by **stbNumber**, **title**, **category**, **language**, and **isHd**, and also able to search by **title** and **stbNumber**. But it seemed like I **couldn't have a map function in a map function**, in this case how do I get other json objects?

list.jsx

```
class List extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            schedules: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('all.json')
            //use es6 arrow function to not lose context of 'this'
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: json.response,
                    schedules: json.response[0].currentSchedule[0],
                })
            }).catch(console.log);
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value});
    };

    render() { 

        var { isLoaded, items, schedules } = this.state;

        // const category = this.getUnique(this.state.items, "category");

        if(!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }

        else {
            return (
            <div className="List">
                <div className="row">
                    {items.map(item => (
                        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12" key={item.id}>
                            <div>
                                    <div className="box">
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="logo-wrap col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-3">
                                                <div>On Now</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-9">
                                                <div className="col-12">{schedules.title}</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))};
                </div>
            </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
 
export default List;
```

I am just starting off with React here and I'm trying my best to understand what I can, now I am stucked at this point and would very much appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You set `schedules: json.response[0].currentSchedule[0],` so your `schedules` only contain the first element of `currentSchedule` and that is an object not an array.

Comment: I tried removing the [0] from both and it looks like `json.response.currentSchedule` , but that gives me error. `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: Should be `json.response[0].currentSchedule` but still it would not have a `title`since it is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the `currentSchedule` is inside each `item`. So you need to access it from there. Also the `currentSchedule` is an array so it does not have a `title` and `eventId`. Those are inside each item of the `currentSchedule`.

So, most likely you do not want to store the `schedules` in the `state` as it is already contained in the `items`.

```
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    items: json.response,
})
```

and when you are iterating over the items, do something like

```js
{ item.currentSchedule.map( (schedule,scheduleIndex) => (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="logo-wrap col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-3">
      <div>{scheduleIndex === 0 ? 'On Now' : schedule.datetime }</div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-9">
      <div className="col-12">{schedule.title}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

for the schedules

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works, now it shows the title correctly there, but how do I trim the time only from `datetime` and make it 12-hour format? and limit the number of retrieved result to a maximum of 3?

Comment: @HaydenNg you will have to first parse the string you have in `datetime` and then format it to the format you want. You can use libraries like [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/) or [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/) to make you life easier.

Comment: Yes yes I just implemented moment and it worked. But how do I set the condition to return only 3 results?

Comment: @HaydenNg You could use `item.currentSchedule.slice(0,3).map`